# Running MS SQL script with batch separators in Ruby/DBI?

Tags: ruby, sql-server, dbi

I am attempting to run MS SQL scripts from files in Ruby/DBI that may contain batch separators (the `GO` keyword.)  The entire script is wrapped in a transaction so that any errors in the script will result in a rollback.

```
  scriptContents = File.read(@path)
  SqlDb.conn['AutoCommit'] = false
  begin
    SqlDb.conn.do scriptContents
    SqlDb.conn.commit
  rescue Exception
    SqlDb.conn.rollback
    @@log.error "Executing #{@path} resulted in error.  Transaction has been rolled back: #{$!}"
  end
  SqlDb.conn['AutoCommit'] = true
```

Executing a simple script that contains a `GO`, such as:

```
PRINT 'this script is pointless'
GO
SELECT 1
```

Results in the following error:

> ERROR  SqlUpgradeScript : Executing test/noop.sql resulted in error. Transaction has been rolled back: 37000 (102) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Removing the `GO` causes the script to run successfully.

What is the cleanest way to run a SQL script that may contain multiple batches with Ruby/DBI, while still running the entire script as a single transaction?

Answer (score 2):

`GO` is not a T-SQL statement. It is a console command used only by SQL Server Management Studio (or the command-line equivalents isq;/osql) to separate batches in scripts files.

Any command text you send to SQL Server is treated as a single batch. Remember, when calling `.do` you are sending a command to the server, not a script file to the console.

In some cases you may have to separate multiple statements with semicolons (`;`), eg when using CTEs ( `WITH () .... SELECT...`) otherwise there is no need to use any separators.

Simply remove `GO` and send the commands you want to the server. If you *do* want to execute script files, you will have to break them in batches in code, then send each batch as a single command.